# Changing CSS media queries for high density mobile screens

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I have a website which is using CSS media queries to alter the design according to the width of the browser window. The widths being targeted are:

990px
620px
440px

This is more to do with the design than any particular device.

This all works fine but when I check the page on a Galaxy A21s the page is not responding as expected. I realise now that this is because the screen resolution of these devices is very high so despite being a mobile the screen width is above 990px all the time.

I have searched around and can't find a good solution to this. I really need the page to function as if it was 1 hardware pixel to 1 CSS pixel or my CSS is going need completely redoing and that is not a desirable option.

So is there a workaround, JS is fine if that has to be used.

Comment: The `width` media query doesn't use hardware pixels; it uses CSS pixels. So it should not be finding a display wider than 990px. Do you have a weird `<meta viewport>` tag by any chance?

Comment: No but that put me on the right track, the page has  a number of frames and although thr meta tag was correct for the frame there was no meta tag in the main page for viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You can check user-agent with [bowser](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser) and select specific mobile device

Also, this [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/07/css-absolute-units/) helps me a lot with pixel density